# How to capture an image or record video with Ionic 3

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

I can't seem to get around these warning & errors when running on a Pixel 2 with Ionic DevApp:

## Warnings and Errors:

```
[09:54:00]  lint finished in 2.37 s
[09:54:24]  console.log: deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
[09:54:24]  console.log: Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded
[09:54:24]  console.log: Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady
[09:54:28]  console.log: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the productionmode.
[09:54:33]  console.warn: Ionic Native: deviceready did not fire within 5000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an
            inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them.
[09:54:33]  console.log: Start Recording
[09:54:33]  console.warn: Native: tried calling MediaCapture.captureImage, 
            but the MediaCapture plugin is not installed.
[09:54:33]  console.warn: Install the MediaCapture 
            plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture'
[09:54:33]  console.error: plugin_not_installed
```

## Steps to reproduce:

Install Ionic

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Start App and run through the following:

1. $ ionic start
2. Project Name: mediacapture
3. Choose a 'blank' ionic-angular project
4. 'Y' - integrate your new app with Cordova...
5. 'Y' - Install the free Pro SDK...
6. cd ./mediacapture
7. Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:
8. $ npm install @ionic-native/core --save
9. $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture
10. $ npm install --save @ionic-native/media-capture
11. Edit the app.module.ts, home.html, & home.ts files as shown below
12. $ ionic serve -lcs

### Add the following to the app.module.ts file

```
import { MediaCapture/*, MediaFile, CaptureError, CaptureImageOptions*/ } from '@ionic-native/media-capture';

providers: [
   ...
   MediaCapture,
```

### Add the following to the home.html file

```
<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button (click)="startrecording()">Start</button>
</ion-content>
```

### Add the following to the home.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MediaCapture, MediaFile, CaptureError, CaptureImageOptions } from '@ionic-native/media-capture';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private mediaCapture: MediaCapture) {

}

startrecording(){
   console.log('Start Recording');
   let options: CaptureImageOptions = { limit: 3 };
   this.mediaCapture.captureImage(options)
     .then(
       (data: MediaFile[]) => console.log(data),
       (err: CaptureError) => console.error(err)
     );
   }
}
```

### Listing plugins show that the Media Capture plugin is installed:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin list
   > cordova plugin ls

  You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
  cordova-plugin-media-capture 3.0.1 "Capture"
```

#### References:

https://ionicframework.com/getting-started

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media-capture/

Comment: is step 12 right? `$ ionic serve -lcs` doesnt run in device...

Comment: I just added more clarification to the top the page. I'm using the Ionic DevApp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MediaCapture plugin does not work in the Ionic DevApp because it is not currently supported. [Here is a list of the currently supported DevApp plugins.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/appflow/devapp#native-cordova-plugin-support)

In order to test the MediaCapture plugin you will need to run the app on a platform or emulator.

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this? If so, could you share it with us? I am facing many problems to get videos from the library ou the camera and by now I could not find any solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @RogerAlmeidaLeite Unfortunately I had to move to a different platform (i.e. Flutter).